# Congruence equation with power solving method

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, chinese-remainder-theorem

How can the equation like
$$
x^{118}\equiv 113\;\; (mod\; 1001)
$$
if I know the Fermat's little theorem, Chinese remainder theorem, Euler's theorem and basic operations on congruence?

**My approach:**

By Euler's theorem we know that if $x\perp 1001 $ then 
$x^{720}\equiv 1 \;\; (mod\; 1001)$
but cannot combine this with my equation.

Comment: 1001 = 7 * 11 * 13

Comment: Prove that $x^{60}\equiv1(\mod1001).$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How did you came out with this idea? Is there so schemma in such problems?

Comment: I used $x^6\equiv1(mod7),$ $x^{10}\equiv1(mod11)$ and $x^{12}\equiv1(mod13).$

Answer (score 2):

Since $1001=7\cdot11\cdot13$ and $(113,1001)=1,$ we obtain
$$x^6\equiv1(mod7),$$
$$x^{10}\equiv1(mod11)$$ and
$$x^{12}\equiv1(mod13),$$ which since $[6,12,10]=60$, gives
$$x^{60}\equiv1(mod1001)$$ and we need to solve
$$x^{-2}\equiv113(mod1001).$$
Now, by the euclidean algorithm we can get that
$$7\cdot1001=62\cdot113+1,$$ which gives
$$62x^{-2}\equiv62\cdot113(mod1001)$$ or
$$62x^{-2}\equiv-1(mod1001)$$ or
$$x^2\equiv-62(mod1001)$$ or
$$x^2\equiv18\cdot1001-62(mod1001)$$ or
$$x^2\equiv134^2(mod1001).$$
Can you end it now?

You can get all eight solutions by the chinese remainder theorem.

We have the following system:
$$x^2\equiv-62(mod7),$$ $$x^2\equiv-62(mod11)$$ and $$x^2=-62(mod13)$$ or
$$x^2\equiv1(mod7),$$ $$x^2\equiv4(mod11)$$ and $$x^2=16(mod13)$$ or

$$x\equiv\pm1(mod7),$$ $$x\equiv\pm2(mod11)$$ and $$x\equiv\pm4(mod13).$$
We got eight systems and it's enough to solve four of them with $x\equiv1(mod7)$ for example.

We have first of these four systems:
$$x\equiv1(mod7),$$ $$x\equiv2(mod11)$$ and $$x\equiv4(mod13).$$
Now, let
$$143a\equiv1(mod7),$$ $$91b\equiv2(mod11)$$ and $$77c\equiv4(mod13).$$
It gives
$$a\equiv5(mod7),$$ $$b\equiv8(mod11)$$ and $$c\equiv9(mod13).$$
Id est,
$$x\equiv5\cdot143+8\cdot91+9\cdot77(mod1001)\equiv134(mod1001).$$
By the same way you can get other six solutions.

Comment: mod 11 not not 10.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee It was typo. Thank you!

Comment: How did you find $18$ for $18\cdot1001-62=134^2$? Trial and error? This gives $2$ solutions ($134$ and $867$). There are $6$ more.

Comment: I don't understand why you get that $x^{60}\equiv 1 \;\;(mod\;1001)$? and after using the euclidean algorithm you get that $ 7\cdot1001-62\cdot113=1$ how is it related to that $x^2\equiv -62\;\;(mod\;1001)?$

Comment: @akozer: $-62\cdot113\equiv1\pmod{1001}$ and $x^{-2}\equiv113\pmod{1001}$ means $x^2\equiv-62\pmod{1001}$. Think reciprocals mod $1001$.

Comment: @akozer I added something. See now.

Comment: @robjohn How did you find out that there are 8 solution to given equation?

Comment: @akozer Solve $x^2\equiv-62(mod7),$  $x^2\equiv-62(mod11)$ and  $x^2\equiv-62(mod13).$ After this you'll get $2^3$ valid solutions and use  the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg But how did you find out that they are different solutions? Did you find them all or they always have to be different ones?

Comment: @akozer I added something. See again.